# Should a progress bar reflect the current step if a user goes back to edit a step?

Tags: checkout, progress-bar, task-flow

I have a simple 4 step process where a user goes into each step, chooses items and checks out at the last step. A fixed overview sits to the left of the page and tells users what their choices have been.

My question is if I reach the last step (4) and I see that I want to edit step 2 should the progress bar go back to step 2 like in the attached image?

Important to note is that the entire process and all steps are on one single page. The user clicks "next" to reveal the next step in the process.

Should I have an indication of completed steps vs. current steps?

Thanks![image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you might be better off conveying both states of use differently.

For example you can make the progress bar move accordingly with the step numbers but also bold/underline the currently viewed step.

So if they get to step 3 and go back to Step 1 then Step 3 will still be orange but it will be obvious that Step 1 is currently being viewed.

[image]

If you do not like the bold/underline idea then maybe draw a gray/black halo around the step number currently being viewed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is good, although we'd need to consider the case when changes in an earlier step invalidate choices in later step that was previously "complete".

Comment: That was mentioned nowhere in the question. I can update my answer if the question changes and I am notified.

Comment: @JimmyJunior brings up a good point but the way it is designed you can't invalidate another step at any point. Awesome suggestion on the underline to indicate the current step. I felt adding more color was too confusing.

Comment: @JimmyJunior You could also make step two slightly transparent like the other steps but still keep it orange to tell the user that he already was at this step, but needs to readjust some things.